# How to get comment images stored as serialized comment meta

Tags: comments, query, attachments, meta-value

I want to display images under for each comment but images store in database as serialized `a:3:{i:0;i:775;i:1;i:776;i:2;i:777;}`
I wrote this code

```
 print_r (get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID , 'reviews-images', true ));
```

but it outputs this *

> Array ( [0] => 778 [1] => 779 [2] => 780 [3] => 781 [4] => 782 ) 10

- 

then I tried this

```
echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'reviews-images', true );
```

not worked . Please help how can I get image urls instead of this output

Answer (score 1):

What you get is fine, it's the image id, now you just need to loop them and output the structure that you want, for example.

```php
if (!empty($images = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID , 'reviews-images', true ))) {
    foreach ($images as $image_id) {
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full');

        // Now you have the image src, $image_src, you can do what ever you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your attention and help. I don,t  understand why? but it does not get any data from ddatabase

Comment: Do some debugging, check what each variable contains and see if it has the correct value. This is a basic structure for your need so you'll need to update it to your need